# Changing android:minSdkVersion either View.animation or .SWF does not work

Tags: android

I have developed an application having android:minSdkVersion=10 in manifest file.
This application is using View.animation(Translataion,Scaling) and calling WebView for .SWF file in two separate activities.

Following thing happens:
1.For android:minSdkVersion=10, I could able to run Animation but not .SWF file on Nexus S having Android 4.1.2.Whereas all I could run on Tablet having Android 2.3.3.

1. For android:minSdkVersion=15, I could able to run .SWF file but not Animation on Nexus S having Android 4.1.2. But Not on Tablet (2.3.3), as expected because Tablet has lower android version.

Query:

Why does changing android:minSdkVersion Nexus showing this result. As for our requirement I need android:minSdkVersion=10 at least.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

This is Probably because nexus s do not support flash player plugin on 4.1 version
if you try to google for it you will find more currently only firefox beta supports flash player plugin in nexus s.........